# jQuery nth-child of element which is a variable, index variable too

Tags: jquery

What's the correct syntax when you want to call the `nth-child` of an element that's a variable and when the index is also a variable.

```
let i = 7;
let listItem = $('#somelist li');

listItem: nth - child(i).css('display', 'none'); // nope
$(`${pageNavLi}:nth-child(${i})`).css('display', 'none'); // nope
```

I've tried a bunch of template strings and can't seem to land it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `get(n)` and supply it with the index. [More info](https://api.jquery.com/get/)

```js
let i = 1;
let listItem = $('li');
console.log(listItem.get(i));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `eq()` to specific child

> **Description:** Select the element at index n within the matched set.

with these

```
listItem.eq(i)
```

OR

```
listItem.filter(':eq(' + i + ')')
```

how to use?

```js
let i = 3;
let listItem = $('#somelist li');

listItem.eq(i).css('display', 'none');
console.log(listItem.eq(i).text())
//OR
listItem.filter(':eq(' + i + ')').css('display', 'none');
console.log(listItem.filter(':eq(' + i + ')').text())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="somelist">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Bubble Milk Tea</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to hide an element by index, you can use jQuery `.eq()`:

```js
let i = 1;
let listItem = $('li');
listItem.eq(i).hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```